# How to create multi-resolution (Retina-ready) NSImage programmatically at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, retina-display

I have two button images, say "myButton.png" and "myButton@2x.png" in my app's bundle resources. At run time, I load the image using [NSImage imageNamed:@"myButton"] and need to split it into three slices and create three NSImages to use in NSDrawThreePartImage() function.

The problem is that each slice NSImage needs to be multi-resolution, so that the system could pick the right resolution dynamically, as it would automatically do with the original whole image.

How do you create the automatic multi-resolution NSImage programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the appropriate solution is to store the image parts in different images and don’t try to code a workaround that splits one image into three parts. This way you can use `NSDrawThreePartImage()` directly and in the most efficient manner.